# How to improve my sql select with indexes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing, innodb

I need help with my sql select.
MySQL 5.7 version

Here is my table

```sql
create table if not exists OffersDayReport
(
    id int auto_increment
        primary key,
    aff_id int not null,
    aff_manager_id int not null,
    source text null,
    adv_id int not null,
    adv_manager_id int not null,
    offer_id int not null,
    offer_category_id int not null,
    country char(2) null,
    browser varchar(255) null,
    deviceType varchar(255) null,
    deviceOS varchar(255) null,
    preLander varchar(11) null,
    goal int null,
    offerPage int null,
    visits int not null,
    clicks int not null,
    conversions int not null,
    payoutInUSD decimal(10,2) not null,
    revenueInUSD decimal(10,2) not null,
    profitInUSD decimal(10,2) not null,
    brokenRevenueInUSD decimal(10,2) not null,
    time int not null,
    constraint unique_row
        unique (time, aff_id, offer_id, source, country, browser, deviceType, deviceOS, preLander, goal, offerPage)
)
charset=utf8;
```

And here is an example of select:

```sql
SELECT OffersModel.lead                                                     as default_lead,
       OffersDayReport.offer_id                                             as report_title_offer_id,
       OffersModel.name                                                     as offers_name,
       sum(OffersDayReport.visits)                                          as report_title_visits,
       sum(OffersDayReport.clicks)                                          as report_title_clicks,
       sum(OffersDayReport.conversions)                                     as report_title_conversions,
       sum(OffersDayReport.payoutInUSD)                                     as report_title_payout,
       sum(OffersDayReport.revenueInUSD)                                    as report_title_revenue,
       sum(OffersDayReport.profitInUSD)                                     as report_title_profit,
       sum(OffersDayReport.conversions) / sum(OffersDayReport.clicks) * 100 as report_title_CR
FROM OffersDayReport
         LEFT OUTER JOIN Offers as OffersModel ON OffersModel.id = OffersDayReport.offer_id
WHERE OffersDayReport.aff_manager_id IN ({numbers})
  AND OffersDayReport.time >= {some start time}
  AND OffersDayReport.time <= {some end time}
GROUP BY OffersDayReport.offer_id;
```

The range could be 1 day and 6 month.
The variability of where clause could be different - with **aff_manager_id** OR **adv_manager_id** OR both etc.

The amount of all rows is big - about 100 billion.
Now my select works about 3-4 minutes, sometimes goes to 10 minutes.
I tried different type of indexes, but mysql analyzer prefer do not use them.
And even if I use `FORCE INDEX()` - all types of indexes that i tried, made my select only slowly.

Comment: Have you looked at range partitioning?

Comment: @Strawberry actually not.

Comment: Then IN numbers for aff_manager how many values does it contain ??? can they be the result of a query ??

Comment: @scaisEdge there are not many numbers. Max is 5.

Comment: i have posted  an answer  hope is useful

Answer (score 0):

be sure you have proper  composite index  on

```
  table  OffersDayReport  columns (time, aff_manager_id )
```

and for Offers table you could use a reduntant composite index ( retriving all the values from index) 
for filter the values  and avoid access to table data

```
  table Offers columns  ( id, name, lead)
```

and last you could try changing you IN clause with an inner join   ..

Another possible improved  could be obtained  changing  the IN clause  in a INNER JOIN . this becuase a IN clause is the same that several OR clause  instead a an INNER JOIN is executed  just one time.
For this

if the ({numbers}) come from  a subquery  you could try using

```
  FROM OffersDayReport
  INNER JOIN  (
    select your_id
    from your_table
    .....
  ) t on t.your_id =  OffersDayReport.aff_manager
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Offers as OffersModel ON OffersModel.id = OffersDayReport.offer_id
  WHERE OffersDayReport.time >= {some start time}
  AND OffersDayReport.time <= {some end time}
```

Otherwise if ({numbers}) are not obtained  by a query  you could build a equivalent result using  an union

```
  select  numbers1 numbers
  UNION
  select  numbers2 
  UNION 
  select  numbers3
  .....
  UNION 
  select  numbersN
```

and for the query

```
   FROM OffersDayReport
  INNER JOIN  (
    select  numbers1 my_number
    UNION
    select  numbers2 
    UNION 
    select  numbers3
    .....
    UNION 
    select  numbersN
  ) t on t.my_number =  OffersDayReport.aff_manager
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Offers as OffersModel ON OffersModel.id = OffersDayReport.offer_id
  WHERE OffersDayReport.time >= {some start time}
  AND OffersDayReport.time <= {some end time}
```

Comment: WHEN? What's WHEN?

Answer (score 0):

First `offers` has little to do with the query, so I'm just going to not consider it (joining it in afterwards should be minor.

Your query is essentially:

```
SELECT odr.OffersDayReport.offer_id, 
       sum(odr.visits) as report_title_visits,
       . . .
FROM OffersDayReport odr
WHERE odr.aff_manager_id IN ({numbers}) AND
      odr.time >= {some start time} ODR
      odr.time <= {some end time}
GROUP BY odr.offer_id;
```

If you could restructure the database, I would recommend an index on `aff_manager_id` and partitioning by `time`.  That is a lot of work on an existing database.

Instead, you can try this much more convoluted form:

```
SELECT odr.OffersDayReport.offer_id, 
       sum(odr.visits) as report_title_visits,
       . . .
FROM ((SELECT odr.*  -- list specific columns you want here
       FROM OffersDayReport odr
       WHERE odr.aff_manager_id = number1 AND
             odr.time >= {some start time} ODR
             odr.time <= {some end time}
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT odr.*  -- list specific columns you want here
       FROM OffersDayReport odr
       WHERE odr.aff_manager_id = number2 AND
             odr.time >= {some start time} ODR
             odr.time <= {some end time}
      ) UNION ALL
      . . .
   ) odr
GROUP BY odr.offer_id;
```

That is, each comparison manager is broken out to a separate query and the results are `UNION`ed together.

Then, be sure you have an index on `(aff_manager_id, time)`.

Each subquery should use the index -- which should be faster.  Then the data brought together for the final aggregation.

You can join in the offer metadata in the outer `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 0):

**Reformulate query to avoid explode-implode**

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT stuff from OffersDayReport GROUP BY offers_id ) a
    LEFT JOIN the other table
```

**Indexes**

> with aff_manager_id OR adv_manager_id OR both etc.

```
INDEX(aff_manager_id, time)
INDEX(adv_manager_id, time)
```

The range part (`time`) is deliberately last.  I did not worry about "or both"; when you have both, the Optimizer will use which one of these is 'better'; that will probably be 'good enough'.  Those indexes may work better when only one manager is indicated, but I think 5.7 has a good enough way of hopping through the index for `IN` so that the `UNION` trick is probably not necessary.

**Shrink footprint**

Do you really need 4 billion possible values for the INTs (4 bytes each)?  Consider smaller variants of INT.

If `source text` is often big and does not lend itself to normalizing, consider compressing it (in the client) and changing the column to `BLOB`.  Text-like stuff typically compresses 3:1.

The country code need be only ascii, not utf8.

On the flip side, will `clicks` and `visits` overflow `INT SIGNED`, which is limited to about 2 billion.  (`INT UNSIGNED` goes to 4B.)

**Normalization**

There would be more than a few thousand different "browsers" out of 100B rows.  Find out how many, then use a suitable INT and normalize the value.  Ditto for the other `VARCHAR(255)` values.  (Beware of "burning" ids.)

That's an awfully big `UNIQUE` index.  Please explain it.

**Summary tables**

This is a potentially big win.  Create a table with subtotals.  Its `PRIMARY KEY` would be `(aff_manager_id, adv_manager_id, dy)`, where dy is the "day" of `time`.  Then, each morning, sum up yesterday's data.  (For this, you might need `INDEX(time)`.)  Then devise a query to sum the sums, etc, to quickly get the desired 'report' from the summary table.  It could (should) have a couple of extra indexes.  Furthermore, the two indexes I suggested for the main ("Fact") table would not be needed.

[*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)